# What is the correct way to make use of correlated messages for TcpOutboundGateway connection to a legacy server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

My understanding is that TcpOutboundGateway is correlating a tcp request and response, but I am not sure how to use this.

The snippet below sends a message via a TcpOutboundGateway to communicate with a legacy system.

```
message = new GenericMessage("ccs?cmd=5&itm="+(16600+t)+"&rf=2");
Test.sendChannel.send(message); // sendChannel is a DirectChannel. 
//Blocks here until reply comes in (in single use and cached)
```

And I have an endpoint to process the response:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "replyChannel")
public void handleReply(byte[] rawRes) {
    // handle the reply.
}
```

handleReply(...) needs context available at the send point in code or vice versa. Using Threadlocal to pass a context to the handler would work (in this case) but seems like a bad idea.

I have looked at the examples, but they seem fairly different to my code (I think because I am using Spring boot) so apologies in advance - I am sure I am overlooking the obvious, but would appreciate some assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can carry a context within `MessageHeaders` for `requestMessage` and `replyMessage` will be supplied with headers from request.

For your POJO handler on `replyChannel` you can add one more method argument with `@Header("myContext")`.